# Is it possible to import Spell Check and Hyphenation Rules from OpenOffice.org?

Tags: hyphenation

Is there a way to import in Mathematica a dictionary(Spell Check and Hyphenation rules) from OpenOffice.org? Or at least, is there a simple way to programatically correct and hyphenate the text in the current cell using such a dictionary?

Comment: it should be possible but it would help if we could see the format of the dictionary you want to import

Comment: If you are on Linux Open/Libre-office usually use something like hunspell, they are located in "/usr/share/myspell" and are in a `.dic` format. Thus you could easily import then.

Comment: @ Öskå  No I am on Windows...! Anyway thanks!